Auth State in Navbar does not update when NextAuth Session expires
I'm facing an issue in NextAuth v4.
I have a Navbar (server component) that is part of my layout. And I render links like "Login" and "Logout" in the Navbar based on the session using getServerSession().
The problem is that when the session expires and I navigate around the app, my route handler redirects me to the / route using the redirect() function from next/navigation. However, the Navbar state doesn't update to reflect the expired session.
This is my code.
layout.tsx
export default async function RootLayout({ children }: RootLayoutProps) {
    return ( 
            <html lang="en"> 
                <body> 
                    <AuthProvider> // Session Provider from NextAuth 
                        <Navbar />
                        <main>
                            {children}
                        </main>

                    </AuthProvider>
                    <Toaster />
               </body>
            </html>
        )
}

Navbar.tsx
import Link from "next/link";
import Logout from "../Logout";
import Login from "../Login";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import authOptions from "@/lib/auth";

export default function Navbar() {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions) 
  return (
    <nav
    >
      <ul>   
        {session ? (
          <li>
            <Logout />
          </li>
        ) : (
          <li>
            <Login />
          </li>
        )}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}

app/home/page.tsx
async function page(props) {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);

  if (!session?.user?._id) {
    redirect("/?error=You are not authenticated");
  }

  return <h1>Welcome, {session.user.username}</h1>
}

So, the redirect function in /home , even though takes me back to "/" route, the Navbar still has Logout button, its state does not update.
Please tell me what am I doing wrong here ?

I advice you to update your version
npm install --save next-auth@5.0.0-beta.4

Your auth.ts file should be looking like this
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import type { NextAuthConfig } from "next-auth"

export const config = {
    trustHost: true,
    providers: [
        //...
    ],
    //...
} satisfies NextAuthConfig

export const { auth, handlers } = NextAuth(config)

Then you can access session in your Navbar component using auth method
import { auth } from "auth"

export default function Navbar() {
    const session = await auth()
    
    return (
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>{session ? <Logout /> : <Login />}</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    )
}

UPDATE
As a better approach, you can redirect unauthenticated users in the middleware
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server"
import { auth } from "auth"

export default auth((request: NextRequest) => {
    // @ts-ignore
    const { auth } = request

    const isLoggedIn = !!auth

    if (!isLoggedIn)
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/?error=You are not authenticated`, request.nextUrl))
})

export const config = {
    matcher: ["/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)"],
}


It does not work. Still, the navbar does not update after session expiry. The reason is redirect() is doing the client side navigation, and it does not refetch the current session.

Then please move your redirection logic into the middleware which is a better approach.

This won't work either, as even from the middleware you would make use of redirect() function and that is what route handlers are also using. So, there is no difference.

Share more code from your project please. How did you set up next auth? Show us.
